# Angular6: Dynamically instantiate (with new) classes including dependency injection

Tags: angular6, factory

I hope anybody can help me with this:

I did not really understand the "Factory Provider" part in the angular.io Documenation and it might not be what I expect it to be..

Here is my problem:

I have a class which should dynamically instantiate a class by a variable. This will be a layer which changes a authentication type by configuration. Like this:

```
const classes = {
    FirebaseAuthService,
    ...
};
```

This constant above defines the possible classes to create.

```
/**
 * returns the auth service
 * for the configured api
 */
auth(key, ...opts) {
    key = TransformHelper.capitalizeFirstLetter(key.toLowerCase());
    const apiClass: AuthInterface = new classes[key + 'AuthService']();
    return apiClass;
}
```

The problem with this is, that classes that will be created have DI which will not be resolved with a simple "new" operator.

Can anybody tell me how to create a sort of a factory which will resolve DI in this case?

Thank you very much!!!